# Understanding an update function. Elapsed time minus itself

Tags: javascript

Im trying to wrap my head around this function. Mainly the NewTime=time-lastTime; line. Why is it needed? What exactly does it do? From what I gather ir takes the elapsed start time which increments starting at zero. Then takes away the last time we saw which will always leave me with the difference of the two times. But how does it use this to update?

```js
let Count = 0;
let interval = 500;

let lastTime = 0;

function update(time = 0) {
  const NewTime = time - lastTime;
  lastTime = time;

  Count += NewTime;
  if (Count > interval) {
    player.pos.y++;
    Count = 0;
  }

  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

Comment: Say you call this function every second. And your interval is 10 seconds. Every time you call this function you add to "Count" 1 second. You get this "second" from time - lastTime. If time = 10 and lastTime = 9, then there you have your second. When Count is greater than interval, you do some shit and restart the Count

Comment: What is the purpose of the program? How you calculate time? The line you mentioned calculates a lapse of time and updates de variable lastTime.

Comment: It looks like this is part of some animation framework that automatically updates something based on the properties of `player`.